# Finding shapefiles of all major cities in world (National and state capitals) at sub-district level?

Tags: shapefile, data

One option is GADM. Having explored this data, while it satifies my need for some cities, its hard to find this data at such a granular level (lower than district level) for most of the cities.

Answer (score 2):

A good source would be OSM and select based on the Admin level.  Downloading all the OSM data for the world would be a pain if you just want cities, but you can try the Metro Areas extract (see [here](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/getting-data/)),